# WebRTC takes time to match OutboundRTPVideoStream frame height & frame width with RTCInboundRTPVideoStream

Tags: webrtc, mediastreamtrack

Even though the constrains[using MediaStreamTrack.applyConstraints()] are in place, the MediaStreamTrack on receivers end have a lower resolution & it slowly adapts to the actual framesize in 10-20 seconds. Is there any way to match the source & destination video track frame size all the time? Attaching the stat details from webrtc internals.

[Stats graphs for RTCInboundRTPVideoStream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfrE3.png)

[Stats graphs for RTCOutboundRTPVideoStream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO00E.png)

Ref:
https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-main/issues/647